# Structures - Two or more data types in declaration specifiers (I have semi-colons)

Tags: c, struct

Not really sure what's causing this,  all I've found on google is that forgetting a semi-colon at the end of my struct causes this but I have one there.

Here's the chunk of code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 20
#define BOOK_NAME_LEN 50
#define AUTHOR_NAME_LEN 30
enum bookStatus {CHECKED_IN, CHECKED_OUT, UNDER_REPAIR, LOST}
enum patronStatus {ACTIVE, INACTIVE}
struct Book{
        char title[BOOK_NAME_LEN];
        char author[AUTHOR_NAME_LEN];
        enum bookStatus status;
};
struct Name{
        char first[NAME_LENGTH];
        char last[NAME_LENGTH];
};
struct Patron{
        int numBooksOut;
        struct Name name;
        struct Book books[50];
        enum patronStatus status;
};
struct Collection{
        struct Book book;
        char title[BOOK_NAME_LEN];
        char author[AUTHOR_NAME_LEN];
        int id, year;
        enum bookStatus status;
};
struct Library{
        int totalPatrons, totalBooks;
        struct Patron patrons[50];
        struct Collection collection[50];
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enums need a semicolon, too.